# Saving OLE Objects in Access field with VBA

Tags: sql-server, object, ms-access, vba, ole

I know that this subject has been covered to large extend, but I have not been able to find a solution to my particular problem.

I have a table with a column **Attachments** of OLE Object data type.  The back end of the table is SQL Server table with VARBINARY(MAX) data type for **Attachments** column.

If I right-click on the **Attachments** field in Access, a menu pops-up with an option to *Insert Object...*  Following this path I could insert a file in the field.

[image]

[image]

The file inserted this way could be opened for viewing and editing just by double-clicking the field.

[image]

Now.  I need to do the same using VBA.  I need to take the list of files and insert them in the **Attachments** field in the appropriate rows.  This should not be a difficult task as it is widely known how to insert a file in a field using ADODB.Stream.  The following is a simple code to try the concept:

```
Private Sub POC()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsa As DAO.Recordset
    Dim stream As ADODB.stream

    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set rsa = db.OpenRecordset("ZipCodeAttachments", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

    rsa.MoveFirst
    rsa.MoveNext

    rsa.Edit

    Set stream = New ADODB.stream
    stream.Type = adTypeBinary
    stream.Open
    stream.LoadFromFile Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Attachments\537.zip"

    rsa.Fields("Attachments").value = stream.Read

    rsa.Update
    rsa.Close

    Set rsa = Nothing
    Set dba = Nothing
End Sub
```

The code inserts a file in the **Attachments** field of the second row.  I could validated that value has been added via SSMS.  However, when I try to open the field for viewing and editing as I did earlier with the first row, this time I am getting an error:

[image]

Clearly, there is something wrong with the way the file is saved with VBA.

What am I doing wrong?  How to achieve the same result with VBA as I get with Access user interface?

Comment: Are you actually using sql server? Everything in your screen shots is from Access.

Comment: An important distinction is: do you want to store files like a file BLOB (blobs are easy to work with through VBA, other programming languages, etc. but hard to work with through the Access GUI) or an OLE Package object (which is easy to work with through the GUI, but near impossible to work with through anything but VBA and hard to work with through VBA)? I can show you how to hack together a way to load an OLE package object from a file into a recordset, but I strongly recommend using normal file BLOBs instead.

Comment: An OLE Object is something like an embedded Word or Excel document, NOT a BLOB. They are supposed to have a very specific file format and can be opened only by their registered applications.. Zips aren't OLE Objects.

Comment: Thanks to everybody for very good questions and willingness to help.

Comment: To Seam Lange:
Yes.  I use SQL Server as a back end.  All data is saved in SQL Server.  I use Access as the front end.

Comment: To Erik von Asmuth:
Erik, I am not sure if I fully understand and appreciate your questions.  So, I will answer to the best of my ability.  I open to storing file in any way or format as long as the back end is SQL Server, and I am able to opening the file for viewing and editing by clicking on the field in Access.
Essentially, I need to reproduce in VBA what I could easily do using Access' user interface.

Comment: To Panagiotis Kanavos:

Either zip-files are OLE objects or not, with Access user interface I am able to insert them in the OLE Object field, view and edit them without any special coding.  I need to do the same with VBA.

Comment: *************** Use the macro recorder. It's a gift. It will write code for you.  ****************

Comment: To nicomp:
Does macro recorder exist in Access 2013 or 2016?  I don't think so.  Are you sure about macro recorder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to store a file as an OLE Package shell object, doing some GUI coding (opening a form with an OLE object, then using that to store the file) is the only way as far as I know.

Create an unbound form called *frmLoadOLEObj*, with on it a bound OLE object called *MyBoundOLEFrame*.

On the form, add the following code:

```vb
Public Sub SaveOLEObj(rs As DAO.Recordset, fldName As String, FileName As Variant)
    'Save the position of the recordset
    Dim bkmrk As Variant
    bkmrk = rs.Bookmark
    'Bind the form to the recordset
    Set Me.Recordset = rs
    'Move the form to the saved position
    Me.Bookmark = bkmrk
    'Bind the OLE frame to the field
    MyBoundOLEFrame.ControlSource = fldName
    MyBoundOLEFrame.Class = "Package"
    'Load the attachment into the OLE frame
    MyBoundOLEFrame.SourceDoc = FileName
    MyBoundOLEFrame.Action = acOLECreateEmbed
End Sub
```

Then, to add a file to a record:

```vb
Dim rsa As DAO.Recordset
Set rsa = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("ZipCodeAttachments", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
Dim frmOLE As New Form_frmLoadOLEObj
frmOLE.SaveOLEObj rs, "Attachments", Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Attachments\537.zip"
```

As you can see, this is very "hacky" code, because it runs GUI operations, and you have code on a form that is not a form, but really a module, but you need a form to put the control on because you can't have the control without the form. I'd rather have a BLOB any day.

Comment: If this fully answers your question, consider accepting it

Comment: Erik von Asmuth,
I think it does answer my question and I will definitely accept it as the answer.  I would like to clarify a a few things, as I face a significant issue, which I hope you might help me to address.
The provided solution works on most files, but fails on files larger than about 20 MB. The statement BoundOLEFrame.Action = acOLECreateEmbed takes about 2.5 minutes to complete.  It does not throw any exceptions, but when the following MoveNext or any re-positioning statement performed, they fail with Run-time error "3426": "The action was cancelled by an associated object."

Comment: As the result of above, the object does not appear to be not stored in the database as attempt to open it with Access UI causes the error: "A problem occurred while Microsoft Access was communicating with the OLE server or ActiveX Control.  Close the OLE server and restart it outside of Microsoft Access.  Then try the original operation again in Microsoft Access."
Suspecting that the issue could be related to ODBC timeout, which is by default is set to 60 seconds, I tried to set the current database QueryTimeout to 600 seconds.  But this did not help...  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue. I suggest you post a separate question about it. Try to provide all the necessary information for me to reproduce it. My database setup is rather fast, so reproducing issues with long load times is hard

Comment: Erik,
My connection to SQL Server is also very fast, but the server is remote and to load 20+MB file even in the local database takes noticeable time.